# I can't float a div

Tags: html

I have an adsense block that I'm adding to wordpress I'm using a plugin to add the shortcode.

I want it to wrap the text around. So I add the code:

```
<div style="float:left;">
ADSENSE CODE
</div>'
```

But it just positions it to the left with the text underneath.

On my other blog, this works just fine. But on a new blog that I'm making it doesn't work at all. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why!

I changed the theme to 2010, 2011 and 2012 and it's always the same. But as I say, on my other blog it works just fine!

I've tried different browsers, cleared cache, etc.

Comment: The code you provided is a joke. You would have to give it to us in context to the surrounding markup.

Comment: Can I just give you the URL? I don't know what other markup you need?

Comment: here's the link: [link](http://www.writing-hub.com/make-money-odesk/)

Comment: Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I would like the text to wrap around the div, but it sits underneath. When I usually do this, the text would go around the div, but this time it doesn't.

Comment: There are 57 `div`s on your page. About which of them is the question?

Comment: The one with the adsense code in it.

Comment: In other words give it an ID or unique class for reference, I don't see a `float:left;` just `class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block;...` inside of a `<div style="left;">
`

Comment: I see the `float:left;` Just before what you have above, there is a definite `<div style="float:left;">`

Comment: The code is exactly the same as another website that I have with the 2012 theme and it works just fine on that site, just not this one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a typo:

```
- <div style="left;">
+ <div style="float:left;">
```

or even better use classes and ids to set it up in a stylesheet that you can use on other pages as well.

```
<style>
.ads{float:left;}
</style>
...
<div class="ads">
```

Comment: I checked that, it was a typo when I was playing around with it. I've since put the float:left; back but it's still the same!

Comment: I just did this and it's the same. The text is still below the div.